# Linking of UITable Objects to URLS in xcode

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

In xcode, how do I link an object to a URL so that when a user taps the object, it automatically links him to the URL. I already have a table view with some objects on it

Comment: Do you want to view the content of the URL in your application, or do you just want to jump the user into Safari to open it?

Comment: I would like just to jump into safari to open it.... Thats all

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to display the content within your application, a UIWebView is what you want to use.

The [UIWebView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has links to several samples.

--- edit ---
To open a URL in Safari, use the `-openURL` method on `UIApplication`. For example:

```
// launch Safari app (we exit)
if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com"]]) { 
    UIAlertView *openURLAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error launching Safari" 
                message:@"Sorry, unable to launch Safari application"
                delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [openURLAlert show];
    [openURLAlert release];
}
```

Comment: I would like to open it with safari

Comment: Thanks for d help..it worked... Now the only problem left is in the detail view after you tap in the table view. I have a label, UIImageView and UITextView. The first two are okay but I don't know how to display data in the UITextView. I want it hardcode inside the coding.